# Удаления символа BOM :(

Tags: javascript, html

Проблема заключается в том, что после названия файла с темой css доставляется символ BOM. Выглядит так:

```
localhost/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/css/skins/purple%EF%BB%BF.css
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Вот скрин отладчика браузера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, что значит после названия файла с темой. это система сборки ? или вы сами переименовываете файл ?

Comment: в sublime есть функция save with encoding -> utf-8 without bom

Comment: @Дмитрий это скорее всего удалит символ только в начале файла.... что-то я сомневаюсь, что везде будет удалён....

Comment: Кто где добавляет-то? Просто взять да стереть backspace'ом, не?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тогда я не очень понимаю откуда у вас этот символ вообще берется

Comment: @Дмитрий лично у меня он ниоткуда не берётся.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/818c48994856d22ccfd776dba2acbfff

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f01964a46ceb85bd3776b8aef008c975